# Cómo compruebo que un valor es distinto a cualquier valor de un array

Tags: php, array, csv

```
{
    name: 'Registros preliminares',
    data: [<?php $numeros = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
    if (($handle = fopen('datos.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($data[3] == '' OR $data[3][0] != DISTINTO A CUALQUIER VALOR DE $NUMEROS){
        $data[3] = 'null';}
    print_r($data[3].",");
}
fclose($handle);}?>]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo con `in_array` así:

```
{
  name: 'Registros preliminares',
  data: [<?php $numeros = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
        if (($handle = fopen('datos.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($data[3] == '' OR !in_array($data[3][0], $numeros))         {
            $data[3] = 'null';}
            print_r($data[3].",");
        }
    fclose($handle);}?>]
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Hace tal cual lo que quería.